# MongoDB - Aggregate and write in sales table

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume there is a collection names productRecord which stores the documents in following way:

```
{
  _id : //id,
  productName : // product name,
  productPrice : //price of product,
  productQuantity: //quantity of product in stock
}
```

and I have recieved sale object(recieved after sale is made) in format:

```
var sale = {
  id : //id
  products : [
     {productId : //id1, qty : //quantity sold},
     {productId : //id2, qty : //quantity sold},
     {productId : //id3, qty : //quantity sold}
   ]
}
```

The id is unique to the sale. I need enter the value in another table named 'saleRecords' in format:

```
{
  id: //id,
  products : [
     {productId : //id1, qty : //quantity sold},
     {productId : //id2, qty : //quantity sold},
     {productId : //id3, qty : //quantity sold}
   ] // same as above ,
   totalsaleprice: //this will be sale.qty * productRecord.productPrice (both related using productId)
}
```

But the price is in the 'productRecord' collection, the qty in the sales record objects and the value needs to be entered in 'salesRecords' connection. How do I write a query for this?

Comment: Is there any possibility that `"_id"` already exists in the `salesRecords` collection?  I.e., when you receive `var sale`, it is a record that should replace any existing `sale._id` already in `salesRecords`?  IOW, `var sale` is not an "edit" to an existing `salesRecords` document?  I'm thinking that an `update` with a pipeline using `"$lookup"` and `"upsert": true` might do the job here.

Comment: @rickhg12hs No its not an edit. We can assume that every var sale is a new record. Every entry made to salesRecord from sale must be a new entry. It is actually a member id that comes with it. Member id is in another collection but we can have multiple salesRecord documents with same member id